# Update odoo custom module using docker-compose

Tags: python, docker, docker-compose, odoo-10

I'm running an Odoo instance in my server using docker-compose. I created a `docker-compose.yml` file as described [here](https://hub.docker.com/_/odoo/):

```
version: '2'
services:
  web:
    image: odoo:10.0
    depends_on:
      - db
    ports:
      - "8069:8069"
    volumes:
      - odoo-web-data:/var/lib/odoo
      - ./config:/etc/odoo
      - ./beralsa/codebis_addons:/mnt/extra-addons
    #command: -- -d odoo -u codebis_purchase
  db:
    image: postgres:9.4
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=odoo
      - POSTGRES_USER=odoo
      - PGDATA=/var/lib/postgresql/data/pgdata
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    volumes:
      - odoo-db-data:/var/lib/postgresql/data/pgdata
volumes:
  odoo-web-data:
  odoo-db-data:
```

I created a custom module and it worked alright. However, I'm unable to update it. I tried using `command` to pass the `-d odoo -u codebis_purchase` but wasn't successful. I also tried putting `update = codebis_purchase` in the `odoo.conf` file, but it was unsuccessful as well.

Any guidance would be appreciated. Let me know if you need any additional info.

Thanks!

Comment: I'm facing exactly the same problem here. Have you found a solution?

Answer (score 1):

I was able to figure this out. I used the following:

```
command: -u module_name -d db_name
```

Then, make sure to use `docker-compose update`, not `docker-compose up`.